# assert using collect and flatten is causing an error (groovy)

Tags: groovy

I have a Json where for each 'optionalPassengerSeqIds' DTO, it displays the value as []. There are 4 of these so when I do a simple log.info on this, it outputs:

```
[[[], [], [], []]]
```

Now I want to do a simple assertion where I want to check each value of this DTO. First I create variable for []:

```
def optionalPassengerSeqIds = []
```

I then flatten the json response for 'optionalPassengerSeqIds' like so:

```
def jsonOptionalPassengerSeqIds = json.groups.options.optionalPassengerSeqIds.flatten()
```

Finally I will do an assertion where I check each value of the json response for 'optionalPassengerSeqIds' DTO matches my 'optionalPassengerSeqIds' variable by using the collect function.

```
assert jsonOptionalPassengerSeqIds.collect{it == optionalPassengerSeqIds}
```

The problem is that I am receiving an error stating:

```
assert jsonOptionalPassengerSeqIds.collect{it == optionalPassengerSeqIds} | | [] []
```

The assertion should pass but I must be doing something wrong in the code. Can I ask what is the issue with my method?

Comment: with empty arrays not clear what you want to check..

Comment: @daggett I just want to be able to check through each value of optionalPassengersSeqIds within the json which is coincidentally are all empty array. Or another option is just check that each value is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check all sub-arrays are empty:

```
def resp=[[[], [], [], []]]
assert resp.flatten().size()==0
```

or check that you have only valid values

```
def resp=[[[1,2],[2,3],[],[]]]
def valid=[2,1,3,4] //all valid values here
def invalid = resp.flatten()-valid
assert invalid.size()==0
```